# nonce for style-src in Rails is added to script-src by mistake

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, content-security-policy

I have a single inline style tag in a Rails app, and I'm trying to whitelist it with a nonce.

The error: `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings observed the loading of a resource at inline (“style-src”). A CSP report is being sent.`

The style gets injected by a helper when using the [invisible_captcha](https://github.com/markets/invisible_captcha) gem:

```
<%= invisible_captcha nonce: true %>
```

Comparing the view and the header shows that the nonce *is* being added to both, but it's being added to `script-src` instead of `style-src`.

View: `<style media="screen" nonce="5Cq/QyoJ5Co+LdarO1uvrg==">`

Header: `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only script-src 'self' https: 'nonce-5Cq/QyoJ5Co+LdarO1uvrg=='; style-src 'self' https:;`

This is my **content_security_policy.rb**:

```
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |config|
 config.style_src  :self, :https    
end

Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_nonce_generator = -> request { SecureRandom.base64(16) }
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_nonce_directives = %w(style-src script-src)
```

Why is it going to the wrong directive, and how can I make it go to `style-src`?

Comment: Can you try to add default_src before script_src?
`config.default_src :self`

Comment: As a purely practical note, why do this inline? Why don't you write a single click handler in an external JS file, and use classes instead of IDs? You just need one, along the lines of `$('.start-chat').click(e => { e.preventDefault(); $(event.currentTarget).attr('href').modal('show') }` and then link the button and its target together by href.

Comment: I honestly didn't know how to do it otherwise. Like, on the page is a list of `purchases`. Each `purchase` renders a `send_message` partial that contains a form for creating a chat between the `current_user` and the other party involved in the `purchase`. To make each form unique, I felt that I had to make a new one for each purchase.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that will interfere with your CSP (or, more accuately, your CSP will interfere with your `<script>` tag).

When using a hash, you need to compute the hash of *every* `<script>` tag, and output the hash in the CSP header as a `script-src`. If you place a literal `<script>` tag in your ERB files, Rails has no way of knowing about that tag, and it won't compute the hash or add it to your header.

Rails (to the best of my knowledge) does not support hashes as a source. You can use the [secure-headers](https://github.com/github/secure_headers) gem, which provides a `hashed_javascript_tag` method to use instead of `<script>`.

Comment: ahhh it says in those docs that hashes are best used to clearlist inline content that's STATIC. https://github.com/github/secure_headers/blob/main/docs/hashes.md

Comment: why you say "every" script tag, do you mean put all of them into one hash?

Comment: @calyxofheld No, they all go into their own hash. Every script tag must be hashed, and its hash must be added to your header. Also, the content doesn't have to be static, so long as you can compute the correct hash for the content you generate. That's easier to do for static content, but the `hashed_javascript_tag` works with any kind of content.